# Python 3 localhost connection

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run the below program but I keep getting connection error's:

```
from socket import *
from codecs import decode

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 5000
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDRESS = (HOST, PORT)

server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
server.connect(ADDRESS)
dayAndTime = decode(server.recv(BUFSIZE), 'ascii')
print(dayAndTime)
server.close()
```

**ERROR:** ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: is there anything listening on port 5000?

Comment: This is my first time coding using ports and host and this code was copied from my textbook so no, I'm not sure. How would I configure this?

Comment: You have to start a server first. Read the textbook more carefully.

Comment: I've read the chapter three times and it does not talk about creating a server. Am I not able to connect to my own computer to get the data/file needed?

Comment: You can only connect to a port your computer if some other program is listing on that port and ready to communicate with you. Were you shown how to set up a server in a previous chapter? Perhaps you're intended to keep it running.

Comment: No I was not shown anything about servers. This is the only chapter that is networking related and it doesn't talk about setting up a server. I am unsure of how to set one up for this project..

Answer (score 3):

If your book doesn't mention the other half of sockets, you need a better book.

Socket basics are easy. You have one process **listen** on a port, waiting for connections. Commonly we'll call this a 'server'. Another process (perhaps on the same machine, perhaps remote) attempts to **connect** to that port. We'll call that the client.

If no one is listening, then when the client attempts to connect they'll get your error `Connection Refused`.

So, set up a listening process. Below, on the left is server code; on the right is client code. Top-to-bottom is the "flow".

```
server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)  # <- just like your example
server.bind(ADDRESS)                   # rather than 'connect', we 'bind' to the port
server.listen(1)                       # bind "claims" the port, so next we call listen & wait...

# Meanwhile...
                                       # Your client process
                                       client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
                                       client.connect(ADDRESS)
# It's only at this moment that the client reaches across the network to the server...
# On connect, the listening server wakes up, and needs to "accept" the connection
(s, remote_addr) = server.accept()
```

Once accepted, you can now send/recv on the `s` socket on the server-side, and send/recv  from the `client` socket on the client side. Note that the `server` variable **is not** the socket to communicate on -- it's used to listen for new connections. Instead, you read/write on the socket object returned as first item of `accept()`.

There's lots more to consider but this is at the heart of the Internet and has been pretty much unchanged since the 1980s.

Image from wikipedia entry for Berkeley Sockets: [image: TCP Socket flow (from wikipedia "Berkeley Sockets")]